# CPP: Escaping macro identifiers

Tags: c++, macros

Is there a way to escape macro names (identifiers) in a c pre processor (cpp) ?

I want to conditionalize some web code (html, css...) with readable macro names.

Example for a conditional css file:

```
/*root*/
some rootcode

#if height==480
/* height 480 */
.page {
    line-height:23px;
}

#elif height<480
/* height < 480 */
.page {
    line-height:46px;
}

#endif
```

An invocation of

```
cpp -P -D height=480 -oout.css css.ccss
```

results in (after deleting newlines)

```
some rootcode
.page {
    line-480:23px;
}
```

but "line-**480**" is wrong.

Is there a way to escape "height" in the code without changing the macro name or stringify it?

Comment: That's one reason most macros are all in CAPS.

Comment: But capitalizing the marco identifier would not solve the problem in general, only minimize it. Imagine a macro identifier "A", and a html site with text. Then every A would be replaced with the value of the macro!

Comment: By using tricks like capitlization and decorating with underscore you *can* solve *your* problem, even if the solution is not the same you pictured in your question.

Comment: I think that CPP is not a good tool for this task.

Comment: Congratulations: that is one of the most dubious use of the CPP I have ever seen.

Comment: surely something like xml+xsl is more suited to this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with the idea of Luchian Grigore to undefine used filenames and I found a (nearly) general solution for this problem:

including a "define.file" at the begin of the conditionals and a "undefine.file" after the given condition.

So the problem is reduced to two macro names, that have to stay: DEFINEFILE und UNDEFINEFILE. But this two macros could be encrypted with their hashcode or with a randomname to avoid a use of this names in the conditional text.

The "define.file":

```
#define height 480
#define os 1
```

The "undefine.file"

```
#undef height
#undef os
```

the "conditionalcss.ccss"

```
/*root*/
some rootcode

#include __DEFINEFILENAMEPATH__

#if height==480
#include __UNDEFINEFILENAMEPATH__
/* height 480 */
.page {
    line-height:23px;
}
#include __DEFINEFILENAMEPATH__

#elif height<480
#include __UNDEFINEFILENAMEPATH__
/* height > 480 */
.page {
    line-height:46px;
}
#include __DEFINEFILENAMEPATH__

#endif

#if os==1
#include __UNDEFINEFILENAMEPATH__
os is windows (if 1 refers to windows)
and height also undefined i hope
#endif
```

Finally the cppcall with the parametric define and undefine files:

```
cpp -P -D __DEFINEFILENAMEPATH__="\"define.file\"" -D __UNDEFINEFILENAMEPATH__="\"undefine.file\"" -oout.css css.ccss
```

With this idea, the restulting "out.css" looks like:

```
some rootcode
.page {
    line-height:23px;
}
os is windows (if 1 refers to windows)
and height also undefined i hope
```

This solution has only the disadvantages of two macros and a possible poor performace because of the multiple imports.

I hope it helps other people to solve their problem.

Greetz
Adreamus

Answer (score 2):

You can either:

1) undefine the macro:

```
#undef height
```

2) rename the macro using standard-like caps:

```
#define HEIGHT
```

3) Use guards before processing the file:

```
#if height==480
#define HEIGHT_480
#undef height
#endif

#if height>480
#define HEIGHT_OVER_480
#undef height
#endif

/*root*/
some rootcode

#if HEIGHT_480
/* height 480 */
.page {
    line-height:23px;
}

#elif HEIGHT_OVER_480
/* height < 480 */
.page {
    line-height:46px;
}

#endif
```

The first one loses information after the undefine. The second one is impractical if there's extensive use of the macro.

The third one is the best option IMO. I've seen it used in production code where stuff like this was necessary.

Comment: I simplified my context a little. Undefining is no option because the cpp-call should be at runtime and a redefine (in front of every new ifdef) is with statical includes not possible. Capitalising would solve some, but not all problems in all textbased documents. The guards are a good idea, but then one has to check, that all code fragments don't use this new name. It is a good idea to minimize the amount of failures, but not a solution for the general problem.

Comment: @Adreamus I don't understand. Runtime has nothing to do with preprocessor definitions (macros). Those are processed even before compilation, let alone runtime.

Comment: If I have a lot of identifiers. One possible solution would be to include in front of every #if or #elif a "define.file" (# define height = 1, #define os = 2) and after this line include a "undef.file" (#undef height, #undef os). But this file is variable and not always on the same place.

Comment: @Adreamus well, for a system as dynamic as the one you described, you can't really have anything static (unless of course you want to build a parser or something). I'm curious myself whether other solutions exist, but I personally can't think of any right now.